# Bibliography [?] Latex

Tags: bibliographies

I want to create a bibliography using Texmaker but it doesn't work. This isn't my  first question about this topic, but I do not understand the answer. Some people suggest me to run the bibtex Here are all my steps:

1. Write my document using the PDFLaTeX compilation function.
2. I want to add a reference to my text, I use the cite function
3. Because I used the cite function, I need to create a .bib file in order to use as my database.
4. When I wrote the bibliography{reference} command, all my other command appear in red and this one is in blue. Is it normal?
5. Then, I created the reference.bib file using the built-in function reference using bibtex. I also compiled this code using the bibtex function (and saved...). Then I get this message: 
   [image]
   My file name is reference.bib, but I don't know what is the "reference.aux" file.
6. Then I came back to my document and compile it in PDFLaTeX and ask to see my PDF. That is what I got:

[image]

I get [?] where I should get something like [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roPc2.jpg).

If it could help you, here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\bibliography{reference}
\begin{document}


 The green apples \cite(Matt)
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

For the reference.bib file, here is the code (this is only an example):

```
@Book{Matt,
ALTauthor = {Matt},
ALTeditor = {•},
title = {Problem with the bibliography},
publisher = {•},
year = {•},
OPTkey = {•},
OPTvolume = {•},
OPTnumber = {•},
OPTseries = {•},
OPTaddress = {•},
OPTedition = {•},
OPTmonth = {•},
OPTnote = {•},
OPTannote = {•}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: you need tocompile your `file.tex` not `reference.bib` using `bibtex` in fact run (pdflatex +bibtex+pdflatex+pdflatex)

Comment: Your reference manager seems to want to help you, but it only confuses you and BibTeX. I would change the properties to be more helpful to you.

Comment: Is there any news here?